# Can an affidavit be used in Beit Din?

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court, legal-documents, edim-witnesses

An [affidavit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affidavit), from what i understand, is basically a signed document given by a witness to be used as evidence in a trial, without the witness themselves needing to take a stand.

**Can an affidavit be used in Beit Din?** Or must witnesses take the stand in person for their testimony to count?

(In case i'm misunderstanding what exactly an affidavit is, simply treat it as a signed document by a witness with their testimony.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sending an "affidavit" it is a dispute between Rashi and Rabbeinu Tam.

[Devarim 19:15](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9983#v=15):

> לא יקום עד אחד באיש לכל עון ולכל חטאת בכל חטא אשר יחטא על פי שני עדים או על פי שלשה עדים יקום דבר

Rashi:

> ולא שיכתבו עדותם באגרת וישלחו לבית דין
>
> And not that they write their testimony in a letter and send it to Beis Din

Tosefos Bava Basra 40a (continued from 39b):

> ועוד אומר ר"י ששמע מן ר"ת שנוהגים לשלח העדים עדותם באיגרת לב"ד וחשיב עדות והא דדרשינן בספרי. מפיהם ולא מפי כתבם לא אתא אלא למעוטי דוקא אלם שאינו בר הגדה אבל ראוי להגדה אין הגדה מעכבת בו
>
> R"i said that he heard from Rabbeinu Tam that the custom is to send testimony by a letter and it is considered [valid] testimony.  And that which it expounds in the Sifre "From their mouths and not from their writing" is only coming to exclude a mute who is not able to speak, but someone who is able to speak does not need to speak.

Rambam concludes it is not allowed, but in monetary law the Chachomim enacted that it would be accepted in order to not prohibit the ability of people to secure loans ([Hilchos Edus 3:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e203.htm#4))

> דין תורה שאין מקבלין עדות, לא בדיני ממונות ולא בדיני נפשות, אלא מפי העדים:  שנאמר "על פי שניים עדים" (דברים יז,ו)--מפיהם, ולא מכתב ידן.  אבל מדברי סופרים שחותכין דיני ממונות בעדות שבשטר, אף על פי שאין העדים קיימין, כדי שלא תנעול דלת בפני לווין.

Comment: +1, but is it brought down according to either opinion by poskim?

Comment: @Cnsersmoit Rabbeinu Tam isn't a posek? :) I wish I knew that offhand.

Comment: @Cnsersmoit I found you a posek. See edit.